# Offline webapp with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, offline, offlineapps

Im creating a Angular Webapp, I need the application to work offline (most of the functionality). According to me almost all the data is required to use the app offline,

1. Angular JS files
2. Images
3. Css files

I read about IndexedDB, it shows we can store the data in object form (key/value pairs). How can i store all my other resources listed above ? Is there any better way to store offline data (local storage also gives only 5mb of storage).

Also read of cache manifest files , but seems thats not a very good way to store larger data.

Comment: So how does this offline webapp gets into the browser in the first place? Is this iOS based webapps? or regular webapp?

Comment: [LocalForage](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/localforage-offline-storage-improved/) looks pretty good for storing offline data. I haven't used it yet. If you have a local webserver running like NodeJS you could store your data in a local mongoDB that's running on the same server. If you don't have a server, I think you need to use something like IndexDB, localStorage or localForage.

Comment: To my understanding IndexedDB and LocalStorage could be vulnerable to cross-directory attack. More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#cross-directory-attacks

Comment: @AWolf LocalForage looks interesting will give it a try in some sample app. Thanks

Comment: @Ved Its a normal desktop browser webapp, the 1st time the user accesses the webapp online its supposed to cache everything to the persons browser, so even if the person is offline he can use the app.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to look into manifest files instead of things like localForage. This way the browser will do all the CSS/HTML/JS bit for you.

See http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html .

If you want to do full synchronisation of database like data you will have a lot more work in store for you though you can take a look at my library / bootstrap for this at https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncItBootstrap

Comment: The issue i read about manifest files is, even if a single line of code is changed then the whole manifest files are downloaded again which is a real big issue... so don't think manifest can be used for big webapps.

Comment: True... It's a fine way to store large amounts of static data, but partial updates require full downloads, so is not partial. You didn't mention partial updates, or any desire to update at all in your question.